# Angular2 - responsive Webapp with different site structure

Tags: angular, web-applications, responsive

I want to build a angular web-app in which i have a overview list which is currently pointing on to a detail page for every list entry.

Because it would be a convenient way to work with these documents, I'd like to show them on desktop on the same page (like detail/overview), but redirect the user to the detail page when everything gets mobile (smartphones and tablets and when the screen width gets to small).

Can this be done with the angular router or do i need to make several components for this?

I'd like to make as much of the "responsive" work with css.